# Strange preferences for Hebrew,Syriac, Bengali,Gurmukhi unicode

Tags: java, unicode, bluej

Someone made me familiar with with Unicode map:
http://www.unicodemap.org/range/11

http://www.unicodemap.org/range/13

http://www.unicodemap.org/range/16

http://www.unicodemap.org/range/17

I decided to test if all the  unicodes were displaying in my BlueJ IDE when I run the code below.
Turns out certain charcters are only displaying in my web browser(firefox), while certain others are only displaying in my IDE. For example, take Hebrew and Bengali. Many Hebrew characters are only displayed in my IDE, while Bengali characters only got displayed in the web browser.

Here is the code  I used :

```
public class printuni
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {     
     int a;
     char c;
     for(a=1400;a<=2700;a++)
     {
        c = (char)a ;
        System.out.format(" %x -",a);
        System.out.println(" integer " + a + " = " + c);       
        }      
    }  }
```

Here is the output(I trimmed it from the end  to limit characters):(What is displayed below in my web browser is different from what  BlueJ IDE displayed. Even though I copy pasted it.)

```
 578 - i 1400 = ո
 579 - i 1401 = չ
 57a - i 1402 = պ
 57b - i 1403 = ջ
 57c - i 1404 = ռ
 57d - i 1405 = ս
 57e - i 1406 = վ
 57f - i 1407 = տ
 580 - i 1408 = ր
 581 - i 1409 = ց
 582 - i 1410 = ւ
 583 - i 1411 = փ
 584 - i 1412 = ք
 585 - i 1413 = օ
 586 - i 1414 = ֆ
 587 - i 1415 = և
 588 - i 1416 = ֈ
 589 - i 1417 = ։
 58a - i 1418 = ֊
 58b - i 1419 = ֋
 58c - i 1420 = ֌
 58d - i 1421 = ֍
 58e - i 1422 = ֎
 58f - i 1423 = ֏
 590 - i 1424 = ֐
 591 - i 1425 = ֑
 592 - i 1426 = ֒
 593 - i 1427 = ֓
 594 - i 1428 = ֔
 595 - i 1429 = ֕
 596 - i 1430 = ֖
 597 - i 1431 = ֗
 598 - i 1432 = ֘
 599 - i 1433 = ֙
 59a - i 1434 = ֚
 59b - i 1435 = ֛
 59c - i 1436 = ֜
 59d - i 1437 = ֝
 59e - i 1438 = ֞
 59f - i 1439 = ֟
 5a0 - i 1440 = ֠
 5a1 - i 1441 = ֡
 5a2 - i 1442 = ֢
 5a3 - i 1443 = ֣
 5a4 - i 1444 = ֤
 5a5 - i 1445 = ֥
 5a6 - i 1446 = ֦
 5a7 - i 1447 = ֧
 5a8 - i 1448 = ֨
 5a9 - i 1449 = ֩
 5aa - i 1450 = ֪
 5ab - i 1451 = ֫
 5ac - i 1452 = ֬
 5ad - i 1453 = ֭
 5ae - i 1454 = ֮
 5af - i 1455 = ֯
 5b0 - i 1456 = ְ
 5b1 - i 1457 = ֱ
 5b2 - i 1458 = ֲ
 5b3 - i 1459 = ֳ
 5b4 - i 1460 = ִ
 5b5 - i 1461 = ֵ
 5b6 - i 1462 = ֶ
 5b7 - i 1463 = ַ
 5b8 - i 1464 = ָ
 5b9 - i 1465 = ֹ
 5ba - i 1466 = ֺ
 5bb - i 1467 = ֻ
 5bc - i 1468 = ּ
 5bd - i 1469 = ֽ
 5be - i 1470 = ־
 5bf - i 1471 = ֿ
 5c0 - i 1472 = ׀
 5c1 - i 1473 = ׁ
 5c2 - i 1474 = ׂ
 5c3 - i 1475 = ׃
 5c4 - i 1476 = ׄ
 5c5 - i 1477 = ׅ
 5c6 - i 1478 = ׆
 5c7 - i 1479 = ׇ
 5c8 - i 1480 = ׈
 5c9 - i 1481 = ׉
 5ca - i 1482 = ׊
 5cb - i 1483 = ׋
 5cc - i 1484 = ׌
 5cd - i 1485 = ׍
 5ce - i 1486 = ׎
 5cf - i 1487 = ׏
 5d0 - i 1488 = א
 5d1 - i 1489 = ב
 5d2 - i 1490 = ג
 5d3 - i 1491 = ד
 5d4 - i 1492 = ה
 5d5 - i 1493 = ו
 5d6 - i 1494 = ז
 5d7 - i 1495 = ח
 5d8 - i 1496 = ט
 5d9 - i 1497 = י
 5da - i 1498 = ך
 5db - i 1499 = כ
 5dc - i 1500 = ל
 5dd - i 1501 = ם
 5de - i 1502 = מ
 5df - i 1503 = ן
 5e0 - i 1504 = נ
 5e1 - i 1505 = ס
 5e2 - i 1506 = ע
 5e3 - i 1507 = ף
 5e4 - i 1508 = פ
 5e5 - i 1509 = ץ
 5e6 - i 1510 = צ
 5e7 - i 1511 = ק
 5e8 - i 1512 = ר
 5e9 - i 1513 = ש
 5ea - i 1514 = ת
 5eb - i 1515 = ׫
 5ec - i 1516 = ׬
 5ed - i 1517 = ׭
 5ee - i 1518 = ׮
 5ef - i 1519 = ׯ
 5f0 - i 1520 = װ
 5f1 - i 1521 = ױ
 5f2 - i 1522 = ײ
 5f3 - i 1523 = ׳
 5f4 - i 1524 = ״
 5f5 - i 1525 = ׵
 5f6 - i 1526 = ׶
 5f7 - i 1527 = ׷
 5f8 - i 1528 = ׸
 5f9 - i 1529 = ׹
 5fa - i 1530 = ׺
 5fb - i 1531 = ׻
 5fc - i 1532 = ׼
 5fd - i 1533 = ׽
 5fe - i 1534 = ׾
 5ff - i 1535 = ׿
 600 - i 1536 = ؀
 601 - i 1537 = ؁
 602 - i 1538 = ؂
 603 - i 1539 = ؃
 604 - i 1540 = ؄
 605 - i 1541 = ؅
 606 - i 1542 = ؆
 607 - i 1543 = ؇
 608 - i 1544 = ؈
 609 - i 1545 = ؉
 60a - i 1546 = ؊
 60b - i 1547 = ؋
 60c - i 1548 = ،
 60d - i 1549 = ؍
 60e - i 1550 = ؎
 60f - i 1551 = ؏
 610 - i 1552 = ؐ
 611 - i 1553 = ؑ
 612 - i 1554 = ؒ
 613 - i 1555 = ؓ
 614 - i 1556 = ؔ
 615 - i 1557 = ؕ
 616 - i 1558 = ؖ
 617 - i 1559 = ؗ
 618 - i 1560 = ؘ
 619 - i 1561 = ؙ
 61a - i 1562 = ؚ
 61b - i 1563 = ؛
 61c - i 1564 = ؜
 61d - i 1565 = ؝
 61e - i 1566 = ؞
 61f - i 1567 = ؟
 620 - i 1568 = ؠ
 621 - i 1569 = ء
 622 - i 1570 = آ
 623 - i 1571 = أ
 624 - i 1572 = ؤ
 625 - i 1573 = إ
 626 - i 1574 = ئ
 627 - i 1575 = ا
 628 - i 1576 = ب
 629 - i 1577 = ة
 62a - i 1578 = ت
 62b - i 1579 = ث
 62c - i 1580 = ج
 62d - i 1581 = ح
 62e - i 1582 = خ
 62f - i 1583 = د
 630 - i 1584 = ذ
 631 - i 1585 = ر
 632 - i 1586 = ز
 633 - i 1587 = س
 634 - i 1588 = ش
 635 - i 1589 = ص
 636 - i 1590 = ض
 637 - i 1591 = ط
 638 - i 1592 = ظ
 639 - i 1593 = ع
 63a - i 1594 = غ
 63b - i 1595 = ػ
 63c - i 1596 = ؼ
 63d - i 1597 = ؽ
 63e - i 1598 = ؾ
 63f - i 1599 = ؿ
 640 - i 1600 = ـ
 641 - i 1601 = ف
 642 - i 1602 = ق
 643 - i 1603 = ك
 644 - i 1604 = ل
 645 - i 1605 = م
 646 - i 1606 = ن
 647 - i 1607 = ه
 648 - i 1608 = و
 649 - i 1609 = ى
 64a - i 1610 = ي
 64b - i 1611 = ً
 64c - i 1612 = ٌ
 64d - i 1613 = ٍ
 64e - i 1614 = َ
 64f - i 1615 = ُ
 650 - i 1616 = ِ
 651 - i 1617 = ّ
 652 - i 1618 = ْ
 653 - i 1619 = ٓ
 654 - i 1620 = ٔ
 655 - i 1621 = ٕ
 656 - i 1622 = ٖ
 657 - i 1623 = ٗ
 658 - i 1624 = ٘
 659 - i 1625 = ٙ
 65a - i 1626 = ٚ
 65b - i 1627 = ٛ
 65c - i 1628 = ٜ
 65d - i 1629 = ٝ
 65e - i 1630 = ٞ
 65f - i 1631 = ٟ
 660 - i 1632 = ٠
 661 - i 1633 = ١
 662 - i 1634 = ٢
 663 - i 1635 = ٣
 664 - i 1636 = ٤
 665 - i 1637 = ٥
 666 - i 1638 = ٦
 667 - i 1639 = ٧
 668 - i 1640 = ٨
 669 - i 1641 = ٩
 66a - i 1642 = ٪
 66b - i 1643 = ٫
 66c - i 1644 = ٬
 66d - i 1645 = ٭
 66e - i 1646 = ٮ
 66f - i 1647 = ٯ
 670 - i 1648 = ٰ
 671 - i 1649 = ٱ
 672 - i 1650 = ٲ
 673 - i 1651 = ٳ
 674 - i 1652 = ٴ
 675 - i 1653 = ٵ
 676 - i 1654 = ٶ
 677 - i 1655 = ٷ
 678 - i 1656 = ٸ
 679 - i 1657 = ٹ
 67a - i 1658 = ٺ
 67b - i 1659 = ٻ
 67c - i 1660 = ټ
 67d - i 1661 = ٽ
 67e - i 1662 = پ
 67f - i 1663 = ٿ
 680 - i 1664 = ڀ
 681 - i 1665 = ځ
 682 - i 1666 = ڂ
 683 - i 1667 = ڃ
 684 - i 1668 = ڄ
 685 - i 1669 = څ
 686 - i 1670 = چ
 687 - i 1671 = ڇ
 688 - i 1672 = ڈ
 689 - i 1673 = ډ
 68a - i 1674 = ڊ
 68b - i 1675 = ڋ
 68c - i 1676 = ڌ
 68d - i 1677 = ڍ
 68e - i 1678 = ڎ
 68f - i 1679 = ڏ
 690 - i 1680 = ڐ
 691 - i 1681 = ڑ
 692 - i 1682 = ڒ
 693 - i 1683 = ړ
 694 - i 1684 = ڔ
 695 - i 1685 = ڕ
 696 - i 1686 = ږ
 697 - i 1687 = ڗ
 698 - i 1688 = ژ
 699 - i 1689 = ڙ
 69a - i 1690 = ښ
 69b - i 1691 = ڛ
 69c - i 1692 = ڜ
 69d - i 1693 = ڝ
 69e - i 1694 = ڞ
 69f - i 1695 = ڟ
 6a0 - i 1696 = ڠ
 6a1 - i 1697 = ڡ
 6a2 - i 1698 = ڢ
 6a3 - i 1699 = ڣ
 6a4 - i 1700 = ڤ
 6a5 - i 1701 = ڥ
 6a6 - i 1702 = ڦ
 6a7 - i 1703 = ڧ
 6a8 - i 1704 = ڨ
 6a9 - i 1705 = ک
 6aa - i 1706 = ڪ
 6ab - i 1707 = ګ
 6ac - i 1708 = ڬ
 6ad - i 1709 = ڭ
 6ae - i 1710 = ڮ
 6af - i 1711 = گ
 6b0 - i 1712 = ڰ
 6b1 - i 1713 = ڱ
 6b2 - i 1714 = ڲ
 6b3 - i 1715 = ڳ
 6b4 - i 1716 = ڴ
 6b5 - i 1717 = ڵ
 6b6 - i 1718 = ڶ
 6b7 - i 1719 = ڷ
 6b8 - i 1720 = ڸ
 6b9 - i 1721 = ڹ
 6ba - i 1722 = ں
 6bb - i 1723 = ڻ
 6bc - i 1724 = ڼ
 6bd - i 1725 = ڽ
 6be - i 1726 = ھ
 6bf - i 1727 = ڿ
 6c0 - i 1728 = ۀ
 6c1 - i 1729 = ہ
 6c2 - i 1730 = ۂ
 6c3 - i 1731 = ۃ
 6c4 - i 1732 = ۄ
 6c5 - i 1733 = ۅ
 6c6 - i 1734 = ۆ
 6c7 - i 1735 = ۇ
 6c8 - i 1736 = ۈ
 6c9 - i 1737 = ۉ
 6ca - i 1738 = ۊ
 6cb - i 1739 = ۋ
 6cc - i 1740 = ی
 6cd - i 1741 = ۍ
 6ce - i 1742 = ێ
 6cf - i 1743 = ۏ
 6d0 - i 1744 = ې
 6d1 - i 1745 = ۑ
 6d2 - i 1746 = ے
 6d3 - i 1747 = ۓ
 6d4 - i 1748 = ۔
 6d5 - i 1749 = ە
 6d6 - i 1750 = ۖ
 6d7 - i 1751 = ۗ
 6d8 - i 1752 = ۘ
 6d9 - i 1753 = ۙ
 6da - i 1754 = ۚ
 6db - i 1755 = ۛ
 6dc - i 1756 = ۜ
 6dd - i 1757 = ۝
 6de - i 1758 = ۞
 6df - i 1759 = ۟
 6e0 - i 1760 = ۠
 6e1 - i 1761 = ۡ
 6e2 - i 1762 = ۢ
 6e3 - i 1763 = ۣ
 6e4 - i 1764 = ۤ
 6e5 - i 1765 = ۥ
 6e6 - i 1766 = ۦ
 6e7 - i 1767 = ۧ
 6e8 - i 1768 = ۨ
 6e9 - i 1769 = ۩
 6ea - i 1770 = ۪
 6eb - i 1771 = ۫
 6ec - i 1772 = ۬
 6ed - i 1773 = ۭ
 6ee - i 1774 = ۮ
 6ef - i 1775 = ۯ
 6f0 - i 1776 = ۰
 6f1 - i 1777 = ۱
 6f2 - i 1778 = ۲
 6f3 - i 1779 = ۳
 6f4 - i 1780 = ۴
 6f5 - i 1781 = ۵
 6f6 - i 1782 = ۶
 6f7 - i 1783 = ۷
 6f8 - i 1784 = ۸
 6f9 - i 1785 = ۹
 6fa - i 1786 = ۺ
 6fb - i 1787 = ۻ
 6fc - i 1788 = ۼ
 6fd - i 1789 = ۽
 6fe - i 1790 = ۾
 6ff - i 1791 = ۿ
 700 - i 1792 = ܀
 701 - i 1793 = ܁
 702 - i 1794 = ܂
 703 - i 1795 = ܃
 704 - i 1796 = ܄
 705 - i 1797 = ܅
 706 - i 1798 = ܆
 707 - i 1799 = ܇
 708 - i 1800 = ܈
 709 - i 1801 = ܉
 70a - i 1802 = ܊
 70b - i 1803 = ܋
 70c - i 1804 = ܌
 70d - i 1805 = ܍
 70e - i 1806 = ܎
 70f - i 1807 = ܏
 710 - i 1808 = ܐ
 711 - i 1809 = ܑ
 712 - i 1810 = ܒ
 713 - i 1811 = ܓ
 714 - i 1812 = ܔ
 715 - i 1813 = ܕ
 716 - i 1814 = ܖ
 717 - i 1815 = ܗ
 718 - i 1816 = ܘ
 719 - i 1817 = ܙ
 71a - i 1818 = ܚ
 71b - i 1819 = ܛ
 71c - i 1820 = ܜ
 71d - i 1821 = ܝ
 71e - i 1822 = ܞ
 71f - i 1823 = ܟ
 720 - i 1824 = ܠ
 721 - i 1825 = ܡ
 722 - i 1826 = ܢ
 723 - i 1827 = ܣ
 724 - i 1828 = ܤ
 725 - i 1829 = ܥ
 726 - i 1830 = ܦ
 727 - i 1831 = ܧ
 728 - i 1832 = ܨ
 729 - i 1833 = ܩ
 72a - i 1834 = ܪ
 72b - i 1835 = ܫ
 72c - i 1836 = ܬ
 72d - i 1837 = ܭ
 72e - i 1838 = ܮ
 72f - i 1839 = ܯ
 730 - i 1840 = ܰ
 731 - i 1841 = ܱ
 732 - i 1842 = ܲ
 733 - i 1843 = ܳ
 734 - i 1844 = ܴ
 735 - i 1845 = ܵ
 736 - i 1846 = ܶ
 737 - i 1847 = ܷ
 738 - i 1848 = ܸ
 739 - i 1849 = ܹ
 73a - i 1850 = ܺ
 73b - i 1851 = ܻ
 73c - i 1852 = ܼ
 73d - i 1853 = ܽ
 73e - i 1854 = ܾ
 73f - i 1855 = ܿ
 740 - i 1856 = ݀
 741 - i 1857 = ݁
 742 - i 1858 = ݂
 743 - i 1859 = ݃
 744 - i 1860 = ݄
 745 - i 1861 = ݅
 746 - i 1862 = ݆
 747 - i 1863 = ݇
 748 - i 1864 = ݈
 749 - i 1865 = ݉
 74a - i 1866 = ݊
 74b - i 1867 = ݋
 74c - i 1868 = ݌
 74d - i 1869 = ݍ
 74e - i 1870 = ݎ
 74f - i 1871 = ݏ
 750 - i 1872 = ݐ
 751 - i 1873 = ݑ
 752 - i 1874 = ݒ
 753 - i 1875 = ݓ
 754 - i 1876 = ݔ
 755 - i 1877 = ݕ
 756 - i 1878 = ݖ
 757 - i 1879 = ݗ
 758 - i 1880 = ݘ
 759 - i 1881 = ݙ
 75a - i 1882 = ݚ
 75b - i 1883 = ݛ
 75c - i 1884 = ݜ
 75d - i 1885 = ݝ
 75e - i 1886 = ݞ
 75f - i 1887 = ݟ
 760 - i 1888 = ݠ
 761 - i 1889 = ݡ
 762 - i 1890 = ݢ
 763 - i 1891 = ݣ
 764 - i 1892 = ݤ
 765 - i 1893 = ݥ
 766 - i 1894 = ݦ
 767 - i 1895 = ݧ
 768 - i 1896 = ݨ
 769 - i 1897 = ݩ
 76a - i 1898 = ݪ
 76b - i 1899 = ݫ
 76c - i 1900 = ݬ
 76d - i 1901 = ݭ
 76e - i 1902 = ݮ
 76f - i 1903 = ݯ
 770 - i 1904 = ݰ
 771 - i 1905 = ݱ
 772 - i 1906 = ݲ
 773 - i 1907 = ݳ
 774 - i 1908 = ݴ
 775 - i 1909 = ݵ
 776 - i 1910 = ݶ
 777 - i 1911 = ݷ
 778 - i 1912 = ݸ
 779 - i 1913 = ݹ
 77a - i 1914 = ݺ
 77b - i 1915 = ݻ
 77c - i 1916 = ݼ
 77d - i 1917 = ݽ
 77e - i 1918 = ݾ
 77f - i 1919 = ݿ
 780 - i 1920 = ހ
 781 - i 1921 = ށ
 782 - i 1922 = ނ
 783 - i 1923 = ރ
 784 - i 1924 = ބ
 785 - i 1925 = ޅ
 786 - i 1926 = ކ
 787 - i 1927 = އ
 788 - i 1928 = ވ
 789 - i 1929 = މ
 78a - i 1930 = ފ
 78b - i 1931 = ދ
 78c - i 1932 = ތ
 78d - i 1933 = ލ
 78e - i 1934 = ގ
 78f - i 1935 = ޏ
 790 - i 1936 = ސ
 791 - i 1937 = ޑ
 792 - i 1938 = ޒ
 793 - i 1939 = ޓ
 794 - i 1940 = ޔ
 795 - i 1941 = ޕ
 796 - i 1942 = ޖ
 797 - i 1943 = ޗ
 798 - i 1944 = ޘ
 799 - i 1945 = ޙ
 79a - i 1946 = ޚ
 79b - i 1947 = ޛ
 79c - i 1948 = ޜ
 79d - i 1949 = ޝ
 79e - i 1950 = ޞ
 79f - i 1951 = ޟ
 7a0 - i 1952 = ޠ
 7a1 - i 1953 = ޡ
 7a2 - i 1954 = ޢ
 7a3 - i 1955 = ޣ
 7a4 - i 1956 = ޤ
 7a5 - i 1957 = ޥ
 7a6 - i 1958 = ަ
 7a7 - i 1959 = ާ
 7a8 - i 1960 = ި
 7a9 - i 1961 = ީ
 7aa - i 1962 = ު
 7ab - i 1963 = ޫ
 7ac - i 1964 = ެ
 7ad - i 1965 = ޭ
 7ae - i 1966 = ޮ
 7af - i 1967 = ޯ
 7b0 - i 1968 = ް
 7b1 - i 1969 = ޱ
 7b2 - i 1970 = ޲
 7b3 - i 1971 = ޳
 7b4 - i 1972 = ޴
 7b5 - i 1973 = ޵
 7b6 - i 1974 = ޶
 7b7 - i 1975 = ޷
 7b8 - i 1976 = ޸
 7b9 - i 1977 = ޹
 7ba - i 1978 = ޺
 7bb - i 1979 = ޻
 7bc - i 1980 = ޼
 7bd - i 1981 = ޽
 7be - i 1982 = ޾
 7bf - i 1983 = ޿
 7c0 - i 1984 = ߀
 7c1 - i 1985 = ߁
 7c2 - i 1986 = ߂
 7c3 - i 1987 = ߃
 7c4 - i 1988 = ߄
 7c5 - i 1989 = ߅
 7c6 - i 1990 = ߆
 7c7 - i 1991 = ߇
 7c8 - i 1992 = ߈
 7c9 - i 1993 = ߉
 7ca - i 1994 = ߊ
 7cb - i 1995 = ߋ
 7cc - i 1996 = ߌ
 7cd - i 1997 = ߍ
 7ce - i 1998 = ߎ
 7cf - i 1999 = ߏ
 7d0 - i 2000 = ߐ
 7d1 - i 2001 = ߑ
 7d2 - i 2002 = ߒ
 7d3 - i 2003 = ߓ
 7d4 - i 2004 = ߔ
 7d5 - i 2005 = ߕ
 7d6 - i 2006 = ߖ
 7d7 - i 2007 = ߗ
 7d8 - i 2008 = ߘ
 7d9 - i 2009 = ߙ
 7da - i 2010 = ߚ
 7db - i 2011 = ߛ
 7dc - i 2012 = ߜ
 7dd - i 2013 = ߝ
 7de - i 2014 = ߞ
 7df - i 2015 = ߟ
 7e0 - i 2016 = ߠ
 7e1 - i 2017 = ߡ
 7e2 - i 2018 = ߢ
 7e3 - i 2019 = ߣ
 7e4 - i 2020 = ߤ
 7e5 - i 2021 = ߥ
 7e6 - i 2022 = ߦ
 7e7 - i 2023 = ߧ
 7e8 - i 2024 = ߨ
 7e9 - i 2025 = ߩ
 7ea - i 2026 = ߪ
 7eb - i 2027 = ߫
 7ec - i 2028 = ߬
 7ed - i 2029 = ߭
 7ee - i 2030 = ߮
 7ef - i 2031 = ߯
 7f0 - i 2032 = ߰
 7f1 - i 2033 = ߱
 7f2 - i 2034 = ߲
 7f3 - i 2035 = ߳
 7f4 - i 2036 = ߴ
 7f5 - i 2037 = ߵ
 7f6 - i 2038 = ߶
 7f7 - i 2039 = ߷
 7f8 - i 2040 = ߸
 7f9 - i 2041 = ߹
 7fa - i 2042 = ߺ
 7fb - i 2043 = ߻
 7fc - i 2044 = ߼
 7fd - i 2045 = ߽
 7fe - i 2046 = ߾
 7ff - i 2047 = ߿
 800 - i 2048 = ࠀ
 801 - i 2049 = ࠁ
 802 - i 2050 = ࠂ
 803 - i 2051 = ࠃ
 804 - i 2052 = ࠄ
 805 - i 2053 = ࠅ
 806 - i 2054 = ࠆ
 807 - i 2055 = ࠇ
 808 - i 2056 = ࠈ
 809 - i 2057 = ࠉ
 80a - i 2058 = ࠊ
 80b - i 2059 = ࠋ
 80c - i 2060 = ࠌ
 80d - i 2061 = ࠍ
 80e - i 2062 = ࠎ
 80f - i 2063 = ࠏ
 810 - i 2064 = ࠐ
 811 - i 2065 = ࠑ
 812 - i 2066 = ࠒ
 813 - i 2067 = ࠓ
 814 - i 2068 = ࠔ
 815 - i 2069 = ࠕ
 816 - i 2070 = ࠖ
 817 - i 2071 = ࠗ
 818 - i 2072 = ࠘
 819 - i 2073 = ࠙
 81a - i 2074 = ࠚ
 81b - i 2075 = ࠛ
 81c - i 2076 = ࠜ
 81d - i 2077 = ࠝ
 81e - i 2078 = ࠞ
 81f - i 2079 = ࠟ
 820 - i 2080 = ࠠ
 821 - i 2081 = ࠡ
 822 - i 2082 = ࠢ
 823 - i 2083 = ࠣ
 824 - i 2084 = ࠤ
 825 - i 2085 = ࠥ
 826 - i 2086 = ࠦ
 827 - i 2087 = ࠧ
 828 - i 2088 = ࠨ
 829 - i 2089 = ࠩ
 82a - i 2090 = ࠪ
 82b - i 2091 = ࠫ
 82c - i 2092 = ࠬ
 82d - i 2093 = ࠭
 82e - i 2094 = ࠮
 82f - i 2095 = ࠯
 830 - i 2096 = ࠰
 831 - i 2097 = ࠱
 832 - i 2098 = ࠲
 833 - i 2099 = ࠳
 834 - i 2100 = ࠴
 835 - i 2101 = ࠵
 836 - i 2102 = ࠶
 837 - i 2103 = ࠷
 838 - i 2104 = ࠸
 839 - i 2105 = ࠹
 83a - i 2106 = ࠺
 83b - i 2107 = ࠻
 83c - i 2108 = ࠼
 83d - i 2109 = ࠽
 83e - i 2110 = ࠾
 83f - i 2111 = ࠿
 840 - i 2112 = ࡀ
 841 - i 2113 = ࡁ
 842 - i 2114 = ࡂ
 843 - i 2115 = ࡃ
 844 - i 2116 = ࡄ
 845 - i 2117 = ࡅ
 846 - i 2118 = ࡆ
 847 - i 2119 = ࡇ
 848 - i 2120 = ࡈ
 849 - i 2121 = ࡉ
 84a - i 2122 = ࡊ
 84b - i 2123 = ࡋ
 84c - i 2124 = ࡌ
 84d - i 2125 = ࡍ
 84e - i 2126 = ࡎ
 84f - i 2127 = ࡏ
 850 - i 2128 = ࡐ
 851 - i 2129 = ࡑ
 852 - i 2130 = ࡒ
 853 - i 2131 = ࡓ
 854 - i 2132 = ࡔ
 855 - i 2133 = ࡕ
 856 - i 2134 = ࡖ
 857 - i 2135 = ࡗ
 858 - i 2136 = ࡘ
 859 - i 2137 = ࡙
 85a - i 2138 = ࡚
 85b - i 2139 = ࡛
 85c - i 2140 = ࡜
 85d - i 2141 = ࡝
 85e - i 2142 = ࡞
 85f - i 2143 = ࡟
 860 - i 2144 = ࡠ
 861 - i 2145 = ࡡ
 862 - i 2146 = ࡢ
 863 - i 2147 = ࡣ
 864 - i 2148 = ࡤ
 865 - i 2149 = ࡥ
 866 - i 2150 = ࡦ
 867 - i 2151 = ࡧ
 868 - i 2152 = ࡨ
 869 - i 2153 = ࡩ
 86a - i 2154 = ࡪ
 86b - i 2155 = ࡫
 86c - i 2156 = ࡬
 86d - i 2157 = ࡭
 86e - i 2158 = ࡮
 86f - i 2159 = ࡯
 870 - i 2160 = ࡰ
 871 - i 2161 = ࡱ
 872 - i 2162 = ࡲ
 873 - i 2163 = ࡳ
 874 - i 2164 = ࡴ
 875 - i 2165 = ࡵ
 876 - i 2166 = ࡶ
 877 - i 2167 = ࡷ
 878 - i 2168 = ࡸ
 879 - i 2169 = ࡹ
 87a - i 2170 = ࡺ
 87b - i 2171 = ࡻ
 87c - i 2172 = ࡼ
 87d - i 2173 = ࡽ
 87e - i 2174 = ࡾ
 87f - i 2175 = ࡿ
 880 - i 2176 = ࢀ
 881 - i 2177 = ࢁ
 882 - i 2178 = ࢂ
 883 - i 2179 = ࢃ
 884 - i 2180 = ࢄ
 885 - i 2181 = ࢅ
 886 - i 2182 = ࢆ
 887 - i 2183 = ࢇ
 888 - i 2184 = ࢈
 889 - i 2185 = ࢉ
 88a - i 2186 = ࢊ
 88b - i 2187 = ࢋ
 88c - i 2188 = ࢌ
 88d - i 2189 = ࢍ
 88e - i 2190 = ࢎ
 88f - i 2191 = ࢏
 890 - i 2192 = ࢐
 891 - i 2193 = ࢑
 892 - i 2194 = ࢒
 893 - i 2195 = ࢓
 894 - i 2196 = ࢔
 895 - i 2197 = ࢕
 896 - i 2198 = ࢖
 897 - i 2199 = ࢗ
 898 - i 2200 = ࢘
 899 - i 2201 = ࢙
 89a - i 2202 = ࢚
 89b - i 2203 = ࢛
 89c - i 2204 = ࢜
 89d - i 2205 = ࢝
 89e - i 2206 = ࢞
 89f - i 2207 = ࢟
 8a0 - i 2208 = ࢠ
 8a1 - i 2209 = ࢡ
 8a2 - i 2210 = ࢢ
 8a3 - i 2211 = ࢣ
 8a4 - i 2212 = ࢤ
 8a5 - i 2213 = ࢥ
 8a6 - i 2214 = ࢦ
 8a7 - i 2215 = ࢧ
 8a8 - i 2216 = ࢨ
 8a9 - i 2217 = ࢩ
 8aa - i 2218 = ࢪ
 8ab - i 2219 = ࢫ
 8ac - i 2220 = ࢬ
 8ad - i 2221 = ࢭ
 8ae - i 2222 = ࢮ
 8af - i 2223 = ࢯ
 8b0 - i 2224 = ࢰ
 8b1 - i 2225 = ࢱ
 8b2 - i 2226 = ࢲ
 8b3 - i 2227 = ࢳ
 8b4 - i 2228 = ࢴ
 8b5 - i 2229 = ࢵ
 8b6 - i 2230 = ࢶ
 8b7 - i 2231 = ࢷ
 8b8 - i 2232 = ࢸ
 8b9 - i 2233 = ࢹ
 8ba - i 2234 = ࢺ
 8bb - i 2235 = ࢻ
 8bc - i 2236 = ࢼ
 8bd - i 2237 = ࢽ
 8be - i 2238 = ࢾ
 8bf - i 2239 = ࢿ
 8c0 - i 2240 = ࣀ
 8c1 - i 2241 = ࣁ
 8c2 - i 2242 = ࣂ
 8c3 - i 2243 = ࣃ
 8c4 - i 2244 = ࣄ
 8c5 - i 2245 = ࣅ
 8c6 - i 2246 = ࣆ
 8c7 - i 2247 = ࣇ
 8c8 - i 2248 = ࣈ
 8c9 - i 2249 = ࣉ
 8ca - i 2250 = ࣊
 8cb - i 2251 = ࣋
 8cc - i 2252 = ࣌
 8cd - i 2253 = ࣍
 8ce - i 2254 = ࣎
 8cf - i 2255 = ࣏
 8d0 - i 2256 = ࣐
 8d1 - i 2257 = ࣑
 8d2 - i 2258 = ࣒
 8d3 - i 2259 = ࣓
 8d4 - i 2260 = ࣔ
 8d5 - i 2261 = ࣕ
 8d6 - i 2262 = ࣖ
 8d7 - i 2263 = ࣗ
 8d8 - i 2264 = ࣘ
 8d9 - i 2265 = ࣙ
 8da - i 2266 = ࣚ
 8db - i 2267 = ࣛ
 8dc - i 2268 = ࣜ
 8dd - i 2269 = ࣝ
 8de - i 2270 = ࣞ
 8df - i 2271 = ࣟ
 8e0 - i 2272 = ࣠
 8e1 - i 2273 = ࣡
 8e2 - i 2274 = ࣢
 8e3 - i 2275 = ࣣ
 8e4 - i 2276 = ࣤ
 8e5 - i 2277 = ࣥ
 8e6 - i 2278 = ࣦ
 8e7 - i 2279 = ࣧ
 8e8 - i 2280 = ࣨ
 8e9 - i 2281 = ࣩ
 8ea - i 2282 = ࣪
 8eb - i 2283 = ࣫
 8ec - i 2284 = ࣬
 8ed - i 2285 = ࣭
 8ee - i 2286 = ࣮
 8ef - i 2287 = ࣯
 8f0 - i 2288 = ࣰ
 8f1 - i 2289 = ࣱ
 8f2 - i 2290 = ࣲ
 8f3 - i 2291 = ࣳ
 8f4 - i 2292 = ࣴ
 8f5 - i 2293 = ࣵ
 8f6 - i 2294 = ࣶ
 8f7 - i 2295 = ࣷ
 8f8 - i 2296 = ࣸ
 8f9 - i 2297 = ࣹ
 8fa - i 2298 = ࣺ
 8fb - i 2299 = ࣻ
 8fc - i 2300 = ࣼ
 8fd - i 2301 = ࣽ
 8fe - i 2302 = ࣾ
 8ff - i 2303 = ࣿ
 900 - i 2304 = ऀ
 901 - i 2305 = ँ
 902 - i 2306 = ं
 903 - i 2307 = ः
 904 - i 2308 = ऄ
 905 - i 2309 = अ
 906 - i 2310 = आ
 907 - i 2311 = इ
 908 - i 2312 = ई
 909 - i 2313 = उ
 90a - i 2314 = ऊ
 90b - i 2315 = ऋ
 90c - i 2316 = ऌ
 90d - i 2317 = ऍ
 90e - i 2318 = ऎ
 90f - i 2319 = ए
 910 - i 2320 = ऐ
 911 - i 2321 = ऑ
 912 - i 2322 = ऒ
 913 - i 2323 = ओ
 914 - i 2324 = औ
 915 - i 2325 = क
 916 - i 2326 = ख
 917 - i 2327 = ग
 918 - i 2328 = घ
 919 - i 2329 = ङ
 91a - i 2330 = च
 91b - i 2331 = छ
 91c - i 2332 = ज
 91d - i 2333 = झ
 91e - i 2334 = ञ
 91f - i 2335 = ट
 920 - i 2336 = ठ
 921 - i 2337 = ड
 922 - i 2338 = ढ
 923 - i 2339 = ण
 924 - i 2340 = त
 925 - i 2341 = थ
 926 - i 2342 = द
 927 - i 2343 = ध
 928 - i 2344 = न
 929 - i 2345 = ऩ
 92a - i 2346 = प
 92b - i 2347 = फ
 92c - i 2348 = ब
 92d - i 2349 = भ
 92e - i 2350 = म
 92f - i 2351 = य
 930 - i 2352 = र
 931 - i 2353 = ऱ
 932 - i 2354 = ल
 933 - i 2355 = ळ
 934 - i 2356 = ऴ
 935 - i 2357 = व
 936 - i 2358 = श
 937 - i 2359 = ष
 938 - i 2360 = स
 939 - i 2361 = ह
 93a - i 2362 = ऺ
 93b - i 2363 = ऻ
 93c - i 2364 = ़
 93d - i 2365 = ऽ
 93e - i 2366 = ा
 93f - i 2367 = ि
 940 - i 2368 = ी
 941 - i 2369 = ु
 942 - i 2370 = ू
 943 - i 2371 = ृ
 944 - i 2372 = ॄ
 945 - i 2373 = ॅ
 946 - i 2374 = ॆ
 947 - i 2375 = े
 948 - i 2376 = ै
 949 - i 2377 = ॉ
 94a - i 2378 = ॊ
 94b - i 2379 = ो
 94c - i 2380 = ौ
 94d - i 2381 = ्
 94e - i 2382 = ॎ
 94f - i 2383 = ॏ
 950 - i 2384 = ॐ
 951 - i 2385 = ॑
 952 - i 2386 = ॒
 953 - i 2387 = ॓
 954 - i 2388 = ॔
 955 - i 2389 = ॕ
 956 - i 2390 = ॖ
 957 - i 2391 = ॗ
 958 - i 2392 = क़
 959 - i 2393 = ख़
 95a - i 2394 = ग़
 95b - i 2395 = ज़
 95c - i 2396 = ड़
 95d - i 2397 = ढ़
 95e - i 2398 = फ़
 95f - i 2399 = य़
 960 - i 2400 = ॠ
 961 - i 2401 = ॡ
 962 - i 2402 = ॢ
 963 - i 2403 = ॣ
 964 - i 2404 = ।
 965 - i 2405 = ॥
 966 - i 2406 = ०
 967 - i 2407 = १
 968 - i 2408 = २
 969 - i 2409 = ३
 96a - i 2410 = ४
 96b - i 2411 = ५
 96c - i 2412 = ६
 96d - i 2413 = ७
 96e - i 2414 = ८
 96f - i 2415 = ९
 970 - i 2416 = ॰
 971 - i 2417 = ॱ
 972 - i 2418 = ॲ
 973 - i 2419 = ॳ
 974 - i 2420 = ॴ
 975 - i 2421 = ॵ
 976 - i 2422 = ॶ
 977 - i 2423 = ॷ
 978 - i 2424 = ॸ
 979 - i 2425 = ॹ
 97a - i 2426 = ॺ
 97b - i 2427 = ॻ
 97c - i 2428 = ॼ
 97d - i 2429 = ॽ
 97e - i 2430 = ॾ
 97f - i 2431 = ॿ
 980 - i 2432 = ঀ
 981 - i 2433 = ঁ
 982 - i 2434 = ং
 983 - i 2435 = ঃ
 984 - i 2436 = ঄
 985 - i 2437 = অ
 986 - i 2438 = আ
 987 - i 2439 = ই
 988 - i 2440 = ঈ
 989 - i 2441 = উ
 98a - i 2442 = ঊ
 98b - i 2443 = ঋ
 98c - i 2444 = ঌ
 98d - i 2445 = ঍
 98e - i 2446 = ঎
 98f - i 2447 = এ
 990 - i 2448 = ঐ
 991 - i 2449 = ঑
 992 - i 2450 = ঒
 993 - i 2451 = ও
 994 - i 2452 = ঔ
 995 - i 2453 = ক
 996 - i 2454 = খ
 997 - i 2455 = গ
 998 - i 2456 = ঘ
 999 - i 2457 = ঙ
 99a - i 2458 = চ
 99b - i 2459 = ছ
 99c - i 2460 = জ
 99d - i 2461 = ঝ
 99e - i 2462 = ঞ
 99f - i 2463 = ট
 9a0 - i 2464 = ঠ
 9a1 - i 2465 = ড
 9a2 - i 2466 = ঢ
 9a3 - i 2467 = ণ
 9a4 - i 2468 = ত
 9a5 - i 2469 = থ
 9a6 - i 2470 = দ
 9a7 - i 2471 = ধ
 9a8 - i 2472 = ন
 9a9 - i 2473 = ঩
 9aa - i 2474 = প
 9ab - i 2475 = ফ
 9ac - i 2476 = ব
 9ad - i 2477 = ভ
 9ae - i 2478 = ম
 9af - i 2479 = য
 9b0 - i 2480 = র
 9b1 - i 2481 = ঱
 9b2 - i 2482 = ল
 9b3 - i 2483 = ঳
 9b4 - i 2484 = ঴
 9b5 - i 2485 = ঵
 9b6 - i 2486 = শ
 9b7 - i 2487 = ষ
 9b8 - i 2488 = স
 9b9 - i 2489 = হ
 9ba - i 2490 = ঺
 9bb - i 2491 = ঻
 9bc - i 2492 = ়
 9bd - i 2493 = ঽ
 9be - i 2494 = া
 9bf - i 2495 = ি
 9c0 - i 2496 = ী
 9c1 - i 2497 = ু
 9c2 - i 2498 = ূ
 9c3 - i 2499 = ৃ
 9c4 - i 2500 = ৄ
 9c5 - i 2501 = ৅
 9c6 - i 2502 = ৆
 9c7 - i 2503 = ে
 9c8 - i 2504 = ৈ
 9c9 - i 2505 = ৉
 9ca - i 2506 = ৊
 9cb - i 2507 = ো
 9cc - i 2508 = ৌ
 9cd - i 2509 = ্
 9ce - i 2510 = ৎ
 9cf - i 2511 = ৏
 9d0 - i 2512 = ৐
 9d1 - i 2513 = ৑
 9d2 - i 2514 = ৒
 9d3 - i 2515 = ৓
 9d4 - i 2516 = ৔
 9d5 - i 2517 = ৕
 9d6 - i 2518 = ৖
 9d7 - i 2519 = ৗ
 9d8 - i 2520 = ৘
 9d9 - i 2521 = ৙
 9da - i 2522 = ৚
 9db - i 2523 = ৛
 9dc - i 2524 = ড়
 9dd - i 2525 = ঢ়
 9de - i 2526 = ৞
 9df - i 2527 = য়
 9e0 - i 2528 = ৠ
 9e1 - i 2529 = ৡ
 9e2 - i 2530 = ৢ
 9e3 - i 2531 = ৣ
 9e4 - i 2532 = ৤
 9e5 - i 2533 = ৥
 9e6 - i 2534 = ০
 9e7 - i 2535 = ১
 9e8 - i 2536 = ২
 9e9 - i 2537 = ৩
 9ea - i 2538 = ৪
 9eb - i 2539 = ৫
 9ec - i 2540 = ৬
 9ed - i 2541 = ৭
 9ee - i 2542 = ৮
 9ef - i 2543 = ৯
 9f0 - i 2544 = ৰ
 9f1 - i 2545 = ৱ
 9f2 - i 2546 = ৲
 9f3 - i 2547 = ৳
 9f4 - i 2548 = ৴
 9f5 - i 2549 = ৵
 9f6 - i 2550 = ৶
 9f7 - i 2551 = ৷
 9f8 - i 2552 = ৸
 9f9 - i 2553 = ৹
 9fa - i 2554 = ৺
 9fb - i 2555 = ৻
 9fc - i 2556 = ৼ
 9fd - i 2557 = ৽
 9fe - i 2558 = ৾
 9ff - i 2559 = ৿
 a00 - i 2560 = ਀
 a01 - i 2561 = ਁ
 a02 - i 2562 = ਂ
 a03 - i 2563 = ਃ
 a04 - i 2564 = ਄
 a05 - i 2565 = ਅ
 a06 - i 2566 = ਆ
 a07 - i 2567 = ਇ
 a08 - i 2568 = ਈ
 a09 - i 2569 = ਉ
 a0a - i 2570 = ਊ
 a0b - i 2571 = ਋
 a0c - i 2572 = ਌
 a0d - i 2573 = ਍
 a0e - i 2574 = ਎
 a0f - i 2575 = ਏ
 a10 - i 2576 = ਐ
 a11 - i 2577 = ਑
 a12 - i 2578 = ਒
 a13 - i 2579 = ਓ
 a14 - i 2580 = ਔ
 a15 - i 2581 = ਕ
 a16 - i 2582 = ਖ
 a17 - i 2583 = ਗ
 a18 - i 2584 = ਘ
 a19 - i 2585 = ਙ
 a1a - i 2586 = ਚ
 a1b - i 2587 = ਛ
 a1c - i 2588 = ਜ
 a1d - i 2589 = ਝ
 a1e - i 2590 = ਞ
 a1f - i 2591 = ਟ
 a20 - i 2592 = ਠ
 a21 - i 2593 = ਡ
 a22 - i 2594 = ਢ
 a23 - i 2595 = ਣ
 a24 - i 2596 = ਤ
 a25 - i 2597 = ਥ
 a26 - i 2598 = ਦ
 a27 - i 2599 = ਧ
 a28 - i 2600 = ਨ
 a29 - i 2601 = ਩
 a2a - i 2602 = ਪ
 a2b - i 2603 = ਫ
 a2c - i 2604 = ਬ
 a2d - i 2605 = ਭ
 a2e - i 2606 = ਮ
 a2f - i 2607 = ਯ
 a30 - i 2608 = ਰ
 a31 - i 2609 = ਱
 a32 - i 2610 = ਲ
 a33 - i 2611 = ਲ਼
 a34 - i 2612 = ਴
 a35 - i 2613 = ਵ
 a36 - i 2614 = ਸ਼
 a37 - i 2615 = ਷
 a38 - i 2616 = ਸ
 a39 - i 2617 = ਹ
 a3a - i 2618 = ਺
 a3b - i 2619 = ਻
 a3c - i 2620 = ਼
 a3d - i 2621 = ਽
 a3e - i 2622 = ਾ
 a3f - i 2623 = ਿ
 a40 - i 2624 = ੀ
 a41 - i 2625 = ੁ
 a42 - i 2626 = ੂ
 a43 - i 2627 = ੃
 a44 - i 2628 = ੄
 a45 - i 2629 = ੅
 a46 - i 2630 = ੆
 a47 - i 2631 = ੇ
 a48 - i 2632 = ੈ
 a49 - i 2633 = ੉
 a4a - i 2634 = ੊
 a4b - i 2635 = ੋ
 a4c - i 2636 = ੌ
 a4d - i 2637 = ੍
 a4e - i 2638 = ੎
 a57 - i 2647 = ੗
 a58 - i 2648 = ੘
 a59 - i 2649 = ਖ਼
 a5a - i 2650 = ਗ਼
 a5b - i 2651 = ਜ਼
 a5c - i 2652 = ੜ
 a5d - i 2653 = ੝
 a5e - i 2654 = ਫ਼
```

How do I display all the unicodes in my blueJ IDE

Comment: This is not a Java question. It's about what the font in your IDE supports. No font that I know of supports *all* of Unicode.

Comment: So how do I change the font of my BlueJ IDE, so that it can display characters of my desire - say Bengali or Gurmukhi?